# Storing hash on blockchain (hash of image stored on ipfs)

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum

I am creating a dapp using react to store images on ipfs and the corresponding hash on the blockchain. The purpose of storing hash on the blockchain is timestamping, proof of ownership etc. and I wish to retrieve the hash also at a later stage. I need to know how can we store and retrieve hash on the blockchain.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose the Ethereum blockchain, the easiest way is to create a smart contract, the simplest example of which is given below.

By calling the **Put** method, you save the data associated with an identifier. The **Get** method allows you to retrieve data by identifier without any cost.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.8 <0.6.0;

contract Storage
{
    address    Owner ;

    mapping (string => string)  Collection ;

//
   constructor() public
   {
              Owner     = tx.origin ;
   }
// 
   function Put(string memory  id_, string memory data_) public
   {
       if(msg.sender!=Owner)  return ;

      Collection[id_]=data_ ;
   }
//
    function Get(string memory  id_) public view returns (string memory retVal)
    {
       return(Collection[id_]) ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to store and retrieve the IPFS hash of an image you can simply use Solidity's [events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events). It may be a bit more complicated but it is **a lot cheaper** to deploy and use the contract.

Here is a basic approach:

```
event Store(string indexed id, string ipfsHash);  //declare event

function setEvent(string memory _id, string memory _ipfsHash)public{
    emit Store(_id, _ipfsHash);
}
```

When you `emit` the `event` in your smart contract, the parameters passed to it are stored in the transaction's logs, a special data structure of the blockchain.

Note that logs and their event data are not accessible within smart contracts. However, you can use libraries such as [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0) inside you app to retrieve them. The use of `indexed` keyword before the `id` parameter let's you effectively search for a particular log, containing a desired value. Without it, you would have to retrieve all logs produced by a particular event and search through them manually.

There are a few ways to retrieve past logs, but i will paste an example using [getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=myContract.getPastEvents#getpastevents) :

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI_of_contract, address_of_contract);

contract.getPastEvents('Store', {
      filter : { id : '...id corresponding to the ipfsHash'},
      fromBlock : 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'},
      function(error, result){

          console.log(result) 

     });
```